# Python function definition on two list

Tags: python, pandas

```
Year   Month   Year_month
2009    2       2009/2
2009    3       2009/3
2007    4       2007/3
2006   10       2006/10

Year_month
200902
200903
200704
200610
```

I would like to combine the year and month columns into the format as Year_month (i.e. replace the original one). How could I do it? The following approach seems not working in Python. Thanks.

```
def f(x, y)
    return x*100+y

for i in range(0,filename.shape[0]):
    filename['Year_month'][i] = f(filename['year'][i] ,filename['month'][i])
```

Comment: What types are the values in each columns? Strings, integers?

Comment: Also, is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: type(filename['month'])
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series

type(RepairTrain['year'])
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['Year_month'] = df.Year.astype(str)  + df.Month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print df
   Year  Month Year_month
0  2009      2     200902
1  2009      3     200903
2  2007      4     200704
3  2006     10     200610
```

Comment: Nope. the string pandas.Series does not offer `zfill`.

Comment: See link. I think it is possible.

Comment: Wow, I could swear I just had it failing. You are correct!

Comment: No problem. Nice day.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.read_clipboard()

Year    Month   Year_month
0   2009    2   2009/2
1   2009    3   2009/3
2   2007    4   2007/3
3   2006    10  2006/10

df['Year_month'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row.Year)+str(row.Month).zfill(2), axis=1)


Year    Month   Year_month
0   2009    2   200902
1   2009    3   200903
2   2007    4   200704
3   2006    10  200610
```